# Missing UV display panel

Tags: uv

While using UV Editing I wanted to use stretch found in the display menu but it is not there.

[image]

Answer (score 2):

In the UV editor use the <kbd>N</kbd> key to open the UV Properties panel then you will find the Stretching option in the View tab > Display > Overlays > Stretching.

[image]